# Using Distinct with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

How would this query be changed from sql to linq?

```
category
select distinct prodCategory from table4

subcategory
SELECT distinct [prodSubCat] FROM [table4] WHERE ([prodCategory] = @prodCategory)


prodCategory    prodSubCat
-------------------------------------
Home            Cassette Receiver
Home            Receiver
Home            cd player
Home            cd player
Home            Receiver
Car             dvd player
Car             GPS
```

Ex.

My Goal is to get prodSubCat for prodCategory = "Car"

```
Car             dvd player
Car             GPS
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Distinct()`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence.

```
IEnumerable<string> category = (from p in t.table4
                                select p.prodCategory).Distinct();

IEnumerable<string> subCategory = (from p in t.table4
                                   where p.prodCategory == "Car"
                                   select p.prodSubCat).Distinct();
```

Comment: table4.AsEnumerable().

Comment: @terrybozzio table4 is an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct` -> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

```
var results = dataContext.Table4.Where(t => t.prodCategory.Equals(prodCategory)).Distinct();
```